# Sense of time: Evaluation and correlation with psychological traits and states

Tags: social-psychology, personality, time, correlation, behavior

Some of us are often in hurry and always late. Some make mistakes while evaluating time-needs for tasks. How is our sense of time connected with our personality? Is it more correlated with the process we are involved in? How we can develop this sense so to make more of our time?

Comment: I have a feeling others will see this as too broad; I had to resist that impulse myself. What do you want to know that's not already covered in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_perception) or all the other questions with the [tag:time] tag? It's not a useless or unclear question, but there's no indication of research effort...Basic answers to your very basic questions may not be worthwhile in the long run, but a slightly more focused version of this could be more valuable IMO. Then again, maybe a broad intro question is justified if that suits the level of the interested audience.

Comment: Thank you! I'll rewrite my question, add more details. Its too wide I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who are [entitled](http://www.sitemaker.umich.edu/eob/files/time2011.pdf) tend to have a slower perception of time. In any given situation, a person can feel some level of entitlement. If a person is waiting in line for 10 minutes to check out groceries, he would experience that 10 minutes as passing by very slowly. On the other hand, if that same person was waiting 10 minutes to meet the President, he would experience the 10 minutes as passing by quickly.

So time perception can be manipulated in any given situation. It depends on the level of entitlement you are feeling in that environment. Perhaps entitlement could artificially be manipulated to create different perceptions of time (e.g. [by thinking quickly and variably](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/can-hypomania-be-induced-by-just-thinking-quickly-and-variably)).

**Source**

*Time Crawls When You're Not Having Fun: Feeling Entitled Makes Dull Tasks Drag On*. Edward H. O'Brien, Phyllis A. Anastasio and Brad J. Bushman, Pers Soc Psychol Bull published online 12 May 2011, DOI: 10.1177/0146167211408922

Comment: I think this is a good answer. In addition, I also want to point out that the sense of fear or trauma tends to dilate the perception of time i.e. you get the feeling that the time isn't moving as quickly as it should. You should check out David Eagleman's experiment that shows this effect. (Ref: Stetson C, Fiesta MP, Eagleman DM (2007) Does Time Really Slow Down during a Frightening Event? PLoS ONE 2(12))